# Using a jQuery fullscreen image gallery in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I have been trying to get malihu's Simple jQuery fullscreen image gallery ( http://manos.malihu.gr/simple-jquery-fullscreen-image-gallery ) to work with my Wordpress theme, but for some reason I'm having trouble getting the script to run. I'm calling both the CSS and javascript normally as with other plugins in the functions.php file, but the javascript doesn't seem to be taking effect to make the gallery. I currently have the following code to call the CSS in the header and the javascript in the footer. Am I missing something?

```
function malihu_gallery() {
if (!is_admin()) {

    // Enqueue Malihu Gallery JavaScript
    wp_register_script('malihu-jquery-image-gallery', get_template_directory_uri(). '/js/malihu-jquery-image-gallery.js', array('jquery'), 1.0, true );
    wp_enqueue_script('malihu-jquery-image-gallery'); 

    // Enqueue Malihu Gallery Stylesheet        
    wp_register_style( 'malihu-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/CSS/malihu_gallery.css', 'all' );
    wp_enqueue_style('malihu-style' );

    }
  }
}

add_action('init', 'malihu_gallery');
```

I'm thinking that I may need to ready the script with something similar to the following, but not sure if I'm on the right track.

```
function gallery_settings () { ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            jQuery('#container').malihu_gallery();
        });
    </script><?php
```

Any help greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Have you referenced jQuery on the page?

Answer (score 0):

If you want any event to work in jQuery you will want it inside document ready. This will load it after the DOM is loaded and before the page content is loaded.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   // your stuff inside of here
 });
```

Not sure based on what you have shown above but try some basic debugging, see if you can call functions when you paste your code into the console. Or if you want to create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) I will take a look.

Comment: Hey cih,
Thanks so much for the reply. I'm still pretty new to wordpress, so not quite sure how to make a fiddle with all the correct parts. I have included the gallery javascript, the plugin CSS and the index.php in the following fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/andyemm/jGN5F/

I have a feeling that the code to run the jQuery in the document is correct, but I'm not sure what to put into the // your stuff inside here portion.

Thanks again, and let me know what else I can do to help.